# how to find the median percentile from a pdf like this?

Tags: probability, percentile

$f(x)=1/3$ if $0<x<1$ and $2<x<4$ and $0$ elsewhere

i found the cdf which is 
     $F(x) = \frac13 x$ for $0<x<1,$ $\frac13$ for $1<x<2,$ $\frac x3-\frac13$ for $2<x<4,$ $1$ for $x>4$

how do i find the 25th and 50th percentile from a cdf like this?

pls help ! thanks

Answer (score 1):

The CDF is
$$F(x) =
\begin{cases}0, &\textrm{if } x < 0 \\
\frac13 x, & \textrm{if } 0\leq x<1 \\
\frac13, & \textrm{if } 1\leq x <2 \\
\frac13 x - \frac13, & \textrm{if } 2\leq x< 4 \\
1, & \textrm{if } x \geq 4
\end{cases}$$

So you can see that your median $x_{0.50} = F^{-1}(\frac12)$ is found by solving
$$\tfrac13 x_{0.50} - \tfrac13 = \tfrac12$$
$$\tfrac13 x_{0.50} = \tfrac56$$
$$x_{0.50}=\boxed{\tfrac52}$$

and the $25^{\textrm{th}}$ percentile $x_{0.25}=F^{-1}(\frac14)$ is found by solving
$$\tfrac13 x_{0.25} = \tfrac14$$
$$x_{0.25}=\boxed{\tfrac34}$$

How did we know which piece of the definition of $F$ to use in each case? By observing that the first piece produces values of $F$ no more than $\frac13$ (that's where $0.25$ lies) and the third piece produces values of $F$ at least $\frac13$ (that's where $0.5$ lies).

In fact, this shows how to compute nearly all percentiles. For $0<p<1$ (except for $p=\tfrac13$), you have

$$x_p = F^{-1}(p) =
\begin{cases}3p, & \textrm{if } 0\leq p<\tfrac13 \\
3p+1, & \textrm{if } \tfrac13 <p\leq 1
\end{cases}$$

For the case $p=\tfrac13$, any number in $[1,2]$ might be considered a valid value for $x_{1/3}$, and different authors define it differently.

Comment: OP knew the CDF but did not know how to post it to this site. The definition was all there in the plain text of the question as originally posted, but most of it was not rendered--specifically everything between a matching < and > (apparently interpreted as HTML delimiters).

Comment: @DavidK: Okay, I didn't see that. I also now realize that I have left off the trivial part of the CDF, so I will add that in. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Of course you didn't see that; you'd have had to be editing the question to see it. :-) Of course _now_ the formatting is fixed, but as you point out, for the sake of completeness there are five pieces of the cdf, not four.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to solve (a) $F(x)=0.25$ and (b) $F(x)=0.50$

Fairly obviously the solution to (a) has $0 \lt x \lt 1$ while the solution to (b) has $2 \lt x \lt 4$

So you need to solve (a) $\frac13x=0.25$ and (b) $\frac x3-\frac13=0.5$, neither of which are difficult

Answer (score 0):

The CDF of your overall variable is the sum of the piecewise CDFs:

$F(x)=\mathbf{1}(x)_{>0}\min\{\frac{x}{3},\frac{1}{3}\}+\mathbf{1}(x)_{>2}\min\{\frac{x-2}{3},\frac{2}{3}\}$